# map Fn + A, S, D, W to cursor keys

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I have a mac keyboard (the aluminium wired one) and as a code monkey I use the cursor keys to move around the screen  a lot. But often I end pressing the cursor keys with my right little finger, which causes me a lot of pain at the end of the day.

Is there a way to map the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> to the cursor keys? I think that will make my life a little pleasant :)

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My standard advice for this is [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele), although I've never tried it.